# System can't find the path specified while running python program in Windows system

Tags: python, windows, operating-system, system, filepath

I am using below line in my code:

```
compress_video(r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\test.mp4", r"C:\Users\User\Downloads\output.mp4", 50 * 1000)
```

I am getting below error:

```
 hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Please help, i am able to run my code in linux machine with below line:

```
compress_video('/Users/witty/Documents/eStudy-Yt.mp4', 'output.mp4', 50 * 1000)
```

Comment: The file Windows can't find is probably the one named in `executable`.

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. What is `compress_video`? I see that in linux code the 2nd argument is a bare filename while in Windows code it's a _full file path_.